# Validation form plugin to use with Ractive.js

Tags: ractivejs

I would like to use a plugin/library for Ractive.js for validating forms, but I can not find any good plugin/library.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are asking for a form validation library recommendation? Or are you asking how to integrate such a library with Ractive?

Comment: I'm asking for a form validation library recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any validation library will do. You just have to wire the library to ractive yourself though. The easiest one I've used was http://validatejs.org/ because it validates plain objects (which work best with observers and `ractive.get()`) and didn't have to deal with forms and the DOM.